# What's a much easier way to clean an ash tray?

Tags: cleaning

I've had this ashtray for about two years. I washed it out only once with soap and warm water, which was a bit of a hassle and still was fully clean.

Any suggestions on a better way to clean it?

[image: dirty ashtray]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oven cleaner, any sort, even the cheap stuff from those really cheap "pound/thrift stores" - it's not as hard to get off as burnt-on grease in an oven, but washing up liquid won't do it unless you scrub.

Just spray it with oven cleaner, then leave it to soak for a couple of hours & it should just rinse clean.

Comment: From the look of that ashtray, a couple of hours might be too long to be without it.

Answer (score 0):

1st make sure there are N0 H0T ASHES, BURNING CIGS/PIPES, OPEN FLAMES, etc, anywhere near cleaning area.
Recommend wearing plastic or rubber gloves. Pour enough rubbing alcohol to cover bottom. Let sit for about 5-10 min, seeing how much build-up is on there. Pour out excess alcohol, preferably outside, as it will have nasty smell of ashtray. Wipe with paper towel, until clean. May use a few alcohol dampened pt's to get clean. Let air dry completely.
If not too much build up, one can use paper towel, damp w/alcohol, to wipe clean. If cleaning pipes &/or Puffer-Snuffer, pipe cleaners & q-tips work even better than pt's.
Alcohol evaporates quickly, when exposed to open air.